# codeigniter - insert array from checkbox

Tags: arrays, checkbox, insert, codeigniter-2

This is my checkbox value in view :

```
$data = array(
'name'        => 'gejala[]',
'value'       => $row->id_gejala.",".$row->id_penyakit,
'checked'     => FALSE,
'style'       => 'margin:10px',
);
```

and next this is my controller :

```
function step2(){

        $a = implode(',',$this->input->post('gejala'));

        $break = explode(',',$a);



        $data = array(

            'id_gejala'=> $break[0],

            'id_penyakit'=>$break[1]

        );



        foreach($data as $penyakit){

            $data[] = array('id_gejala'=> $break[0],'id_penyakit'=>$break[1]);

        }

        print_r($data);

    }
```

Example result in my browser :

```
Array ( [id_gejala] => 58 [id_penyakit] => 6  )
```

My question, how to insert the result to database ?
Maybe it look like here :

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
id + id_gejala + id_penyakit
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
1  +     58    +     6     +
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your controller you need to write

```
$this->insert_model->insert($data);
```

In the insert_model you need to insert the data in that form:

```
class Insert_model extends CI_Model { // Name just for example
    function Insert_model() {
        parent:: __construct();

    }


    function insert($data) {
        $this->db->insert('table_name', $data); // Write the name of table
    }

}
```

If you have any problem, just tell me in comment. 
Thanks